how to show this.variable value in observer callback function in chrome debug mode
In angular application, given the following code:
this.f55Service.getByFormDeif55Key(this.formDeif55Key).subscribe(data => {
          this.stiFormDeif55Dto = data.body; 
          console.log(data.body);
});

this.f55Service.getByFormDeif55Key(this.formDeif55Key) returns an Observable, I set an breakpoint in
console.log(data.body);

so to ensure that
this.stiFormDeif55Dto = data.body; 

is run, then in chrome debug console, I type this.stiFormDeif55Dto but it returns undefined, if I point the mouse cursor to stiFormDeif55Dto variable in the line
this.stiFormDeif55Dto = data.body; 

it also returns undefined.
So how to show the value of the variable this.stiFormDeif55Dto in debug mode console?


Unfortunately no, because stiFormDeif55Dto variable is the variable that only within the scope in your component. Probably you need to declare a global variable with window like this answer but not encourage it, as this allow the value change (done in console) for the variable.

When you place the breakpoint after the line this.stiFormDeif55Dto = data.body; and when debug (the compiler passed this line), you mouse over to the this.stiFormDeif55Dto, it should able to show the value.

no, still undefined when the mouse over to the this.stiFormDeif55Dto

Since the variable is defined within the scope of that component, unfortunately you can't access it while debugging in the chrome developer console.
However there is a neat extension, suggested by Angular, (Angular DevTools) you could install on either chrome or firefox.
Once installed, go into developer tools and select the Angular tab. There you will be able to see the components listed in a tree. Click on your component and on the right side, your properties such as stiFormDeif55Dto will be listed with the current value of it.
You can even edit and modify the value of the property!
Have fun!

My project is using angular 5.2.10, so cannot use Angular DevTools.

@user1169587 well, it is never too late to upgrade the project :D. Jokes aside, I highly recommend upgrading your Angular project. Other than that, unfortunately I don't think I could provide another solution for your debugging issue.
